# Number of $n$ digit numbers where sum of no three consecutive digits is greater than $0\leq S \leq 9$?

Tags: combinatorics

This problem is inspired by the less general question

> number of 20 digit numbers where sum of no three consecutive digits is greater than 9?

Note I make one crucial assumption. That is that $0 \leq S \leq 9$. Just to make things simpler for me.

I first tried to figure out how many three digit numbers there existet such that the digit sum is equal or less than $S$. (looking away at the first one). We have 10 possibilities for the first digit (0-9), then we have (S-first) and for the last we have a total of S-first-second, or in math speak

$$
  \sum_{i=0}^S \sum_{j=0}^{S-i} \sum_{k=0}^{S-i-j} 1 = \frac{(s+3)(s+2)(s+1)}{6}
$$

Since the order of the numbers does not matter we have to multiply it with 6! (I think).

Then I tried figuring out how many such 3-digit combinations could be placed inside a $n$-digit number. I thought it would just be $n - 3$. However this was as far as I have gotten. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This looks fairly complicated. Even for the simplest non-trivial case of $n$ digits and $s=1$ it is not obvious what the answer is in closed form.

Comment: How should I make it clearer? The question I ask is in the title, and my work is towards the title. The quote is to show the background for the question. I am unsure how to make this clearer. Please feel free to edit.

Comment: Try developing a recurrence.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you call the quote a less general question -- I've removed my comment. The quote formatting is usually used to highlight the question you're asking, so it's visually slightly misleading to use it to highlight a different question that you're not asking.